# Is there any Google Slide AppScript trigger function called when the presenter progresses from slide-to-slide?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'd like to perform an action (while I'm presenting a Google Slides App) each time I progress from one slide to another. Is there such a trigger? If there isn't how could I implement that?

Looking at the progress example (https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script/blob/master/slides/progress/progress.gs) that's just generates the progress bar into each slide during installation.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. In that example it looks like it generates static bars and puts them in each existing slide. It doesn't update dynamically.

Comment: There isn't a trigger for slide change, but you can create Chrome extension that will track slide change, here's sample one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remote-for-slides/pojijacppbhikhkmegdoechbfiiibppi?hl=en

Comment: @Kos that's actually a good idea for an implementation, although it'll be outside of AppScripts. But can fulfill what I'd like to do  (send notification when slide change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Unfortunately Google Apps Script hasn't a built-in feature to implement custom-triggers.

Reference

- [Available types of triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers)

Comment: Oh yes, I saw that graphic